# Headless chrome geolocation

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, headless

Dose anyone know how to set Geo-location in Headless chrome?

I have been researching for how to set-up and found following article.
But, I do not know how to set this thing up.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

My environment is here.

Ubuntu 18.04
Chrome: 67.0.3396.99

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for commenting on an old post, but I could find nothing else that referred to headless chrome geo location issues.

I've found out that you cant, accepting geo location is currently not supported in headless Chrome. Headless is a stripped down version of Chrome

See reference:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11542#issuecomment-1380947933